# golang thread safe map with channel as values for thread safe

Tags: dictionary, concurrency, go

i use [this](https://github.com/streamrail/concurrent-map) as concurrentmap,and  buffer channels as map value for thread safe(worked as queue),when test use 10 goroutines the value got from channel was not same with the one send in,any suggestion?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/streamrail/concurrent-map"

func main() {
    testmap := cmap.New()
    fmt.Println("SyncMapNew:    ", TestInParallel(&testmap, 10))
}

func TestInParallel(g *cmap.ConcurrentMap, n int) time.Duration {
    start := time.Now()
    var wait sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        wait.Add(1)
        go func() {
            TheTest(g, rand.New(rand.NewSource(int64(i*500))))
            wait.Done()
        }()
    }
    wait.Wait()
    return time.Now().Sub(start)
}

func TheTest(g *cmap.ConcurrentMap, rnd *rand.Rand) time.Duration {
    start := time.Now()
    var key string
    var value time.Time
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        key = strconv.Itoa(int(rnd.Int31n(50000)))
        if g.Has(key) == false {
            g.Set(key, make(chan time.Time, 100))
        }
        tchan, _ := g.Get(key)
        castchan := tchan.(chan time.Time)
        value = time.Now()
        castchan <- value
        got := <-castchan
        g.Set(key, castchan)
        if value != got {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("ERROR: expected %v, got %v", value, got))
        }
    }
    return time.Now().Sub(start)
}
```

**update**i misunderstand the business logic,the code should like this

```
key = strconv.Itoa(int(rnd.Int31n(500)))
tchan, _ := g.GetSet(key, make(chan time.Time, 100))
castchan := tchan.(chan time.Time)
value = time.Now()
if len(castchan) >= 99 {
   <-castchan//do somthing here
}
castchan <- value
g.Set(key, castchan)
```

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/RqxEjTei2e

Comment: Given the defeciencies in the "concurent-map" package you're using (some mentioned in [David Budworth's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30339509/55504), there are more), and the ease of which you can add `sync.Mutex` yourself which locks what you actually need (which is often a little more than individual map accesses) I see no reason to use the package.

Answer (score 0):

You are using random keys, so more than one goroutine may get the same random number.

if two routines get the same number at the same(ish) time, then

This is a race condition:

```
if g.Has(key) == false {
    g.Set(key, make(chan time.Time, 100))
}
```

It is possible that h.Has is false for two goroutines at the SAME time and then they both set, so goroutine1 sets chan A, and goroutine2 sets chan B and then both end up using chan B

In order to solve this, you need something like

```
SetIfAbsent
```

Which locks, checks if it exists, and if not, sets it, then unlocks.

The library you linked map isn't super useful as a cache in that it provides no atomic SetIfAbsent type function.

---

In the event there isn't a g.Has / g.Set race, then if two routines just happen to get the same key, and thus, same channel, you aren't guaranteed which value is first in queue and which is read first.

so goroutine1 might read the value goroutine2 put in, or the other way around.

When thinking about using shared state in a concurrently executing system, you have to assume that any other operation may happen between any statements / lines of code.

I often like to think of it as, you should assume that each line of your code is run on each core one at a time.

so, in Has/Set example it would be:

```
if g.Has(key) == false { // goroutine1
if g.Has(key) == false { // goroutine2
    g.Set(key, make(chan time.Time, 100)) //goroutine1
    g.Set(key, make(chan time.Time, 100)) //goroutine2 
} //goroutine1
} //goroutine2
tchan, _ := g.Get(key) //goroutine1
tchan, _ := g.Get(key) //goroutine2
```

see where the bug is?  the second routine put it's channel in the map, but both retrieved that same channel on the tchan line.

make sense?

Comment: hi,i know the situation you describe so i try to find and write a thread safe map,i test with this https://gist.github.com/craigmj/5770480 ,but all three structs  are  slow

Comment: Do you mean to keep reusing the same keys over and over again? You're running 10k iterations over just 500 keys (so they're going to collide a lot). What actual use case are you trying to optimize? Your "set and immediately read" makes certain kinds of optimizations impossible (you can't batch writes). Is that your expected use? What kinds of keys do you really expect to use? How many? How much memory are you willing to spend for performance (with enough memory, you can use an array rather than map)? Are keys really random (there are benefits we could exploit there)? Use cases matter.

Comment: @RobNapier,the key and value need be reused in real condition,the post code is just to test the channel work as a FIFO queue,finally i realize i miss understand the business logic